# How to get server info from WMSCapabilitiesStore

Tags: wms, geoext

I am using the following code to retrieve a list of data layers hosted on a WMS Server:

```
var store = new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore({ url: fullUrl });

// Add some callbacks to handle various situations  
store.on('load',      successFunction);
store.on('exception', failureFunction);

store.load(); 


function successFunction(store, records) 
{
    // Generate a nice table or something
}
```

That works well enough for retrieving layer data, but while I am connecting to the server, I also want to get the service/title attribute for the server itself.  That data is contained in the server's response to the GetCapabilities request, and it must be stored somewhere, but I can't figure out how to retrieve it from the data returned to successFunction.